# Making/Saying oaths in mind

Tags: sunni, islamic-scholar, oaths

If you make or say an oath in your mind and your lips are closed but your tongue is moving inside your mouth would that be valid?

Comment: No, you'd have to say it out loud for it to be valid

Comment: @YoMango even if your tongue is moving from the inside of your mouth?

Comment: You can't say things in your mind and your tongue moves in pronouncing it without opening your mouth.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean its not possible

Comment: @IbrahimHammed Ohh so it's not valid?

Comment: Yeah, as @YoMango said.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to say it loud and from your heart, or just keep quiet.